# new Joda DateTime object, weird TimeZone (-0752)

Tags: datetime, timezone, jodatime

I am using the `Joda Time` library to print out a timestamp, and for the most part, it is working. But when I create a new `DateTime` object like such:

```
// leftThumbIndex corresponds to a RangeBar position
DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(1000, 1, 1, leftThumbIndex, 0, 0, 0);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Log.e("start", formatter.print(startDateTime));
```

I am printout out the results and this is what I get:

```
1000-01-01T23:00:00.000-0752
```

So it is giving me a weird TimeZone. I thought the timezones were in increments of 100... ie -0800, -0500, etc

**What is going on here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem derives from the medieval date you are using.

Joda-Time, by default, uses the [ISO](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_iso.html) chronology, which is inaccurate for historical dates before 1583. If you don't need to use historical dates, the default ISO chronology should be fine.

If you do want to work with historical dates, you could look into the Julian chronology, or, even better, the [Gregorian-Julian](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_gj.html) chronology.

Also, between timezones there's not necessarily 1 hour increments. There's a number of 30 minute and 45 minute difference timezones out [there](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The `TimeZone` has been adjusted, but now it is showing -0800 which is off by 1 hour. Should be -0700 which I am assuming is because of Daylight Savings. Do you know the fix for this? If not, no worries! Thanks for the answer again... would have never figured it out!

Comment: Most likely daylight savings indeed, but unsure why you would want to fix this. For all intents and purposes it's a correct representation.